# VBA- How to add another IF Not item filter to code?

Tags: vba

```
         If Not (IsDate(TextBox11)) Or Date > CDate(TextBox11) Then
             Select Case MsgBox("You've entered letters/past date, try again! MM/DD/YYYY Format!", vbRetryCancel)
```

Cell N29 on Sheet10 (hidden) identifies a future date.

Trying to add a third option to this IF NOT based if the date input is beyond this future date.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please separate the test/msg pairs, and finally see if there is a msg to tell the user.  Now this can be easily extended to have more tests and msg-s.

```
Private Sub TextBox11_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If TextBox11.Text <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        msg = ""
         If Not (IsDate(TextBox11)) Then
            msg = "Not a date: use MM/DD/YYYY Format!"
         ElseIf Date > CDate(TextBox11) Then
            msg = "You've entered letters/past date, try again!"
         End If
         If msg <> "" Then
             Select Case MsgBox(msg, vbRetryCancel)
                Case vbRetry
                     Cancel = True
                Case vbCancel
                     TextBox11.Text = vbNullString
             End Select
         Else
             TextBox11 = Format(CDate(TextBox11), "mm/dd/yyyy")
         End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another ElseIf like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox11_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If TextBox11.Text <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        msg = ""
         If Not (IsDate(TextBox11)) Then
            msg = "Not a date: use MM/DD/YYYY Format!"
         ElseIf Date > CDate(TextBox11) Then
            msg = "You've entered letters/past date, try again!"
         ' LOOK HERE
         ElseIf Date < CDate(TextBox11) Then
            msg  = "You have entered letters/future date, try again!"
         End If
         If msg <> "" Then
             Select Case MsgBox(msg, vbRetryCancel)
                Case vbRetry
                     Cancel = True
                Case vbCancel
                     TextBox11.Text = vbNullString
             End Select
         Else
             TextBox11 = Format(CDate(TextBox11), "mm/dd/yyyy")
         End If
    End If
End Sub
```