# Highlight with exeption Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need help figuring out how it's possible to highlight duplicates but not highlight or compare to values that has "IMD Exempel" in column A.

This is my code right now but it highlights every duplicate.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Set Rng = Range(Range("C8"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each cel In Rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cel.Value) > 1 Then
        cel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
    Else
        cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
Next cel
```

In this example screenshot I would like none to be highlighted.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA- How to add another IF Not item filter to code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189968/vba-how-to-add-another-if-not-item-filter-to-code)

Comment: If you have another question,  please ask it as ... another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `COUNTIFS():`

```
Dim Rng As Range, Rng_A As Range
Dim cel As Range
Set Rng = Range(Range("C8"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set Rng_A = Range(Range("A8"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
For Each cel In Rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rng, cel.Value, Rng_A, "<>IMD Exempel") > 1 Then
        cel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
    Else
        cel.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End If
Next cel
```

**Updated Code:**

```
Dim Rng As Range, Rng_A As Range
Dim cel As Range, LastRow As Long, i As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Range(Range("C8"), Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set Rng_A = Range(Range("A8"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For i = 8 To LastRow
        If (WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rng, Cells(i, 3).Value, Rng_A, "<>IMD Exempel") > 1) And (Cells(i, 1).Value <> "IMD Exempel") Then
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
        Else
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
Next i
```

1. Have added extra condition to not highlight if A's value is `IMD Exempel`
2. As we cannot filter that A's value, we are using `Cells()` over `range` and tweaking the `FOR loop` a bit
3. We are using `Lastrow` manually and feeding into `FOR loop`

In the above code, I have added another condition to check i.e., `<> IMD Exempel`

Comment: Thank you, it almost work. If I for example change C15 to KV01-MF41, same as C13 and C17. Then all three gets higlighted, but I only want C13 and C15 since C17 has "IMD Exempel" in A17.

Comment: Gotcha! Have updated the answer. Check it out! (updated code)

Comment: Thank you! It works perfect! :) I discoverd another problem but I was not allowed to post it in this thread so if you can and want help me out with that one too check out the link below :) @Arun
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70551298/highlight-if-match-in-other-column-excel-vba